# rails3.2+rspec+capybara1.0 test devise google-oauth2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, oauth-2.0, capybara

i'm using capybara 1.0 with ruby 1.9.2 rails 3.2
This is my test:

```
#spec/features/google_login_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe "the signin process", type: :feature do
  before do
    puts user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) #/users/auth/google_oauth2
    visit  user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2)
  end
  it {#somethings}
end
```

but i have this error:

```
  Failures:

  1) the signin process 
     Failure/Error: visit  user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2)
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/o/oauth2/auth"
     # ./spec/features/google_login_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

my routes file is this

```
#config/routes.rb
Booking::Application.routes.draw do
  #https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview#using-omniauth-without-other-authentications
  devise_for :users , controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks"}
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'sign_in', :to => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    get 'sign_out', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end
end

$rake routes
user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/:provider(.:format)        users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/google_oauth2/}
user_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) users/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:google_oauth2)
new_user_session GET      /sign_in(.:format)                     devise/sessions#new
destroy_user_session GET      /sign_out(.:format)                    devise/sessions#destroy
```

the applications works fine, there is no problem. The problem is when capybara visit the user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2).
I have no idea to solve, can you help me?

***SOLUTION:***

```
#spec/features/google_login_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe "the signin process", type: :feature do
  before do
    puts user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) #/users/auth/google_oauth2
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium #change drive according whit https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#drivers 
    visit  user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2)
  end
  it {#somethings}
end
```

Comment: Could you post the output of "rake routes" from the command line?

Comment: Yes, now i m going to edit original post adding the output of  rake routes

Comment: Try user_omniauth_authorize_path(:provider => :google_oauth2), shouldn't matter, but it's possible.

Comment: just tried doesn't works

Comment: You sure that's the whole test? It says the error is on line 9.

Comment: yes, is the whole test. The original file has some blanck lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default RackTest driver used by Capybara does not support redirection to an external site. You'll need to use Selenium or another alternative driver.

See https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#drivers for instructions on selecting a driver.