# rails+capybara+selenium testing google oauth2 callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara

i'm using selenium to test my google oauth2 login:

```
#spec/featurers/google_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "the signin process", type: :feature do
    before do
      Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
      visit  user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2)
      fill_in "Email", :with => 'test@gmail.com'
      fill_in "Password", :with => 'test'
      click_button 'Accedi'
      #in this point it crash
      click_button 'Consenti'
    end
    it { page.should have_content('Google') }
end
```

it works but i have a problem to manage google callback:

```
Errore:redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: http://127.0.0.1:58272/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback did not match a registered redirect URI
```

how can i manage this callaback? if a make a realy test, instead 127.0.01:58272 i have localhost:3000 and it works.

***SOLUTION***

in spec_helper.rb or, more specific, in yours spec file in a before block.

```
describe "the signin process" do
  before do
    Capybara.run_server = true #Whether start server when testing
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
    Capybara.server_host= 'localhost' #this is the goal 
    Capybara.server_port = 3000
    visit user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2)
  end
  it {#some}
end
```

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20388082/rails3-2rspeccapybara1-0-test-devise-google-oauth2-0

Comment: i have a different problem, i m able to visit external links, but i'm not able to manage the callback url

Answer (score 0):

The `redirect_uri` does only work if you have generated a client ID in your console on https://code.google.com/apis/console/ .

When creating the client ID you have to choose `Installed Application`to make it work. Further information about generating the client ID: https://developers.google.com/console/help/#generatingoauth2

Comment: i have just posted my solution

Comment: so you have created a client ID for 127.0.0.1:3000 in your google console? Keep in mind that by setting the test environment's port to 3000 you will have to make sure that no server in development mode runs on port 3000.